# Unable to read stdout and stderr for a long running process in paramiko with channels and exec_command

Tags: python, paramiko

I am running to run a long running process on a server (a remote machine) from a Python process on my machine (the local machine).

I'm able to start and execute the process successfully using Paramiko's `exec_command` function, and it works great. However, the code that I am running on the remote machine is a long running process, and I wish to perform some checks on the output / the log. That is to say, I want to read the output while it is running and check for certain keywords within the output.

I put together a minimal working example to illustrate this. Instead of checking for certain keywords, I print the output to the screen.

When I run the following, I get all the output together once the process ends. I am not able to get the output as an when it is being printed by the remote process.

I've even tried using `setblocking` and `settimeout` to no avail.

I have the following file, that I run from my laptop.

```
import sys
import paramiko
import os
import select
import getpass
import time

rpi = {
    "username": getpass.getuser(),
    "hostname": "hostname.of.server.here"
}

command = "cd /path/to/folder/ && python test_worker.py"
ssh = paramiko.SSHClient()
ssh.load_system_host_keys()
ssh.set_missing_host_key_policy(paramiko.AutoAddPolicy())
ssh.connect(**rpi)
ssh_stdin, ssh_stdout, ssh_stderr = ssh.exec_command(command)

def worker(stdout, stderr):

    # Wait for the command to terminate
    print("Status of worker is {}".format(stdout.channel.exit_status_ready()))
    while not stdout.channel.exit_status_ready():
        time.sleep(1)
        print("Status of worker is {}".format(stdout.channel.exit_status_ready()))
        if stdout.channel.recv_ready():
            # Only print data if there is data to read in the channel
            print("Worker stdout.channel.recv_ready: {}".format(stdout.channel.recv_ready()))
            rl, wl, xl = select.select([stdout.channel], [], [], 0.0)
            if len(rl) > 0:
                # Print data from stdout
                print("Output: {}".format(stdout.channel.recv(1024).decode("utf-8")))

print("Reading output from master")
worker(ssh_stdout, ssh_stderr)
print("Finished reading output from master")
```

The test_worker.py file is as follows:

```
import time
import sys

i = 0

while True:
    time.sleep(5)
    i = i + 5
    print("At time {}".format(i))
    if i > 15:
        sys.exit(0)
```

This is the output I get at the moment,

```
$ python paramiko_runner.py                                                                                                                                                                                                                    
Reading output from master
Worker function printer
Status of worker is False
Status of worker is False
Status of worker is False
Status of worker is False
Status of worker is False
Status of worker is False
Status of worker is False
Status of worker is False
Status of worker is False
Status of worker is False
Status of worker is False
Status of worker is False
Status of worker is False
Status of worker is False
Status of worker is False
Status of worker is False
Status of worker is False
Status of worker is False
Status of worker is False
Status of worker is False
Status of worker is False
Status of worker is False
Status of worker is True
Worker stdout.channel.recv_ready: True
Output: At time 5
At time 10
At time 15
At time 20

Finished reading output from master
```

Comment: Can you get the output continuously (not at once) using any other way? Like using command-line `ssh` or `plink`?

Comment: If I ssh into the remote machine as an interactive session, and then cd into the folder and run the `python test_worker.py`, I'm able to get the output continuously. I can try other methods now.

Comment: If I run this `ssh hostname.of.server.here python /path/to/folder/test_worker.py`, I get the output all at once, and not continuously. However, if I use `ssh -t hostname.of.server.here python /path/to/folder/test_worker.py`, I get the output continuously. Hmm. So do I HAVE to force pseudo-tty allocation in order to get the stdout and stderr back continuously?

Comment: I was able to use `ssh_stdin, ssh_stdout, ssh_stderr = ssh.exec_command(command, get_pty=True)` to solve this.

Answer (score 0):

I believe you have to get_pty if you want to read continuous values. You can do the following:

```
ssh_stdin, ssh_stdout, ssh_stderr = ssh.exec_command(command, get_pty=True)
```

Comment: Beware, that using get_pty can bring you nasty side effects. Did you try changing `test_worker.py` to flush its output using `sys.stdout.flush()`?

Comment: I haven't tried that yet. I will and get back to you. Can you elaborate on what side effects get_pty has?

Comment: PTY signalizes to the server that the client is used interactively by a human (what is not true in your case). That can make the server use lots techniques to make the experience better for the human. Those techniques can easily break your code. They includes things like coloring the output using ANSI escape sequences. Paginating the output (waiting for key press once a [non existent] screen fills). Etc. Moreover these techniques can "improve" when the server gets upgraded, so your code can break any time in future, when the upgrade occurs. You should never enable PTY when automating.